# Use of "multipart/form-data"

Tags: html

Does the `multipart/form-data` value of the `enctype` `<form>` attribute has any use except for in forms that contain a `<input type="file" />`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At this stage multipart/form-data is used only for sending files via the input[type=file] element:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4.2

Comment: Could you elaborate on how may it be possible to submit `multipart/form-data` data without `<input type="file" />` ?